# change style if element contains a specific child

Tags: jquery

I want to write in jquery: if .mainbody contains the child .post-123 then change the height of .mainbody to 300px.

I tried to do write it like this

```
   if ($('.mainbody').contains('.post-123')) {
    $(".mainbody").css({ 'height': "300px" });
}
```

and also

```
if($('.mainbody .post-123')).length > 0){
    $(".mainbody").css({ 'height': "300px" });
}
```

But it didn't work, what did I do wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: change contains to `x.has('.post-123')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `has` instead

```
$('.mainbody:has(.post-123)').css('height', '300px')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kk17426c/)

Answer (score 0):

Use 'has' instead of 'contains'.

[contains](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/): will return true or false

[has](http://api.jquery.com/has/): constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements.

```
$('.mainbody:has(.post-123)').css('height', '300px');
```